# Django manage different forms in a same page in view.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my project i have to manage 3 different forms in my login html file, one for classic login, one for user registration and one for company registration (all in a single login.html file)
I create in my forms.py three different Modelforms class for manage the different models but now i have just an url and in my views.py i dont know how to say for witch form the data come from and how make the binding and the elaboration:

```
def user_login(request, log_err=None):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/log_error')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'l_err': log_err})
```

How can i discriminate the saving data into correct model if come from form1,2 or 3?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: So all forms have the same fields? In your UI are you reusing the same form with different buttons for each or so you have completely separate forms for each

Comment: Hi, no, the three forms have different fields, and different <forms> tags

Answer (score 1):

You can set a different name for each submit button and then check which one is clicked and then pass the data to the corresponding form:

```
<form method="POST">
    { fields ... }
    <button type="submit" name="company">Rgister Company</button>
</form>

<form method="POST">
    { fields ... }
    <button type="submit" name="register">Rgister</button>
</form>

<form method="POST">
    { fields ... }
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

And then check the data in view:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    if 'login' in request.POST:
        # Login form
    elif 'register' in request.POST:
        # Register form
    elif 'company' in request.POST:
        # Company registration form
```